# how can i remove item from Qtreeview?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtreeview

basically i want to remove item from Qtreeview on the dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) inherited
in a qtreeview subclass. 
what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get to the model with http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#model method. You can get index under current mouse pos with http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt method. At the end you can use http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRow to remove desired index

Comment: Note that the usage of removeRow when you have a QModelIndex is this:  `model->removeRow(index.row(), index.parent());`